# Can I make a project reference use a reference path instead, if the project output doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, csproj

I tried searching stackoverflow.com and google for any answers, but couldn't find anything with the same situation I have.

I am working on a solution from source control, where I am only making changes to one project in the solution. The solution has 34 project references to projects in this solution which require a whole Synergy development environment to build. Since I do not have a Synergy development environment set up, I had another developer build the projects and send me the assembly files, and I removed the project references from the project I am working on, and added assembly references instead.

Checking in actual changes to the project file are becoming a hassle, because I have to merge and remove my assembly references for the project references, and then re-do the whole process of removing project references for assembly references after checking in the change, so it will build for me again.

I was wondering if there was any way to make a project reference use reference paths, so that if the output from the project doesn't exist, it will look for the assembly in the folder specified by the reference path?

Comment: can you utilize some of the build actions for pre and post..?

Comment: Yes. I know what pre-build and post-build events are.. what specifically are you thinking?

Comment: I think I would try to get around that by just checking in as I went and then fixing up the references before a final check in before the branch is merged in.

Comment: @JonHanna That is basically what I am doing now. I'm trying to find an easier way.

Comment: could you not create a folder that global to the project perhaps a dependency folder.. put all the dll's there and when the project builds it will re-build as necessary.. and you would not have to add and remove once you set it up in the project..

Comment: @MethodMan So you are saying that I should create a folder in the project in visual studio, and add the dll files to that folder through visual studio, and then change the project references to file references to those files? If that is what you mean, that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to accomplish, which is to keep the project references, and have visual studio find the assemblies at another location, specified by the "reference path" set up in the project I'm building.

Comment: @Zack you are making this harder than it needs to be.. I use this approach currently and have zero issues with project builds with way more projects in a single solution that you are currently talking about and everything works perfect.. perhaps you need to understand more about how assemblies and references work.. good luck

Comment: I think you need to understand more about what I'm actually asking, instead of assuming that I don't understand how assemblies and references work. Did my previous comment accurately describe what you are suggesting? I feel like you did not give a very clear description of your solution...